What logical fallacy is ‘X is Y, but if you are X that doesn't do Y, then this statement doesn’t apply to you’?
I'm idly curious because I've been trying to think which logical fallacy/ies this scenario would fit nicely under. It comes up all the time in discussions of gender online. The most recent example I saw was:

'Men sexually harass and assault women, but if you're a man that doesn't do this then this statement does not apply to you.'

I've been racking my brains trying to slot it nearly under one fallacy. Almost feels like a spin off of a no true Scotsmen. Any ideas?
Thanks :)

IMHO The statement is an awkward attempt to avoid the hasty generalization fallacy.

The example is not really a fallacy. When they say "men sexually harass and assault women," it doesn't mean "all men sexually harass and assault women," it means some men do. This would be consistent with some men not doing that.
Compare it to, "soldiers kill people." This is a statement most would agree with. But most soldiers will never kill anyone. Observe what happens if we divide the number of wartime deaths by the (usually several times greater) number of soldiers. Since there are several times more soldiers than deaths, most soldiers cannot be individually responsible for a death.
Or compare it to, "The mob was throwing bricks at the police." The number of people throwing bricks is typically going to be a tiny fraction of the number of people in any given protest. But because some people did throw bricks, it is a conventional use of language to say that the mob as a whole was throwing bricks.
However, such statements are not very technically precise, and they do tend to stereotype a whole group based on the actions of what may be a minority. Such statements paint a picture that subtly connotes and pushes the reader towards thinking that the typical (e.g. vast majority) member of the group is guilty, even though in many cases that isn't true.
It would be more accurate - and less manipulative - to specify "some" or "most" as the case may be, or if possible to give an actual fraction that did.

I think "Dogs ride skateboards" is perhaps a more useful example. Some do, the vast majority don't, and most people would consider the statement at least somewhat misleading.

Not sure if there is a specific name for this phenomenon. It's not per se a fallacy, but it suggests both stereotyping or overgeneralization plus a form of tokenism (the one exception that is known about -- or accepted as exception -- is ignored as challenge to the stereotype). So, perhaps "tokenism" is a good name?
Actually, there does turn out to be a name -- this is the same as the "No true Scotsman" fallacy as the OP suggested (I didn't see it the first time...). See: No true Scotsman. In this case, the argument would be that no 'true' or no 'common, average' man (no man as found most everywhere) is like the exceptional non-harassing man.
The extra twist which does seem to make the argument a bit manipulative (as @causative also suggested) is that the exceptional man is the "you". This "you" may feel flattered by being portrayed in a more positive light, but would be justified to wonder "Why me? How come I'm the exception?" Being flattered, or perhaps a bit confused, the "you" might not ask this question. But then the line of argumentation plays in on a cluster or general psychological biases that we all consider ourselves to be more exceptional (mostly in "good" ways) than we really are (or than others consider ourselves to be).
Most people (apart from me) consider themselves to be exceptional individuals.

I hereby convert a comment by @Conifold to an answer so that it is not lost and add some remarks:

These are called generic generalizations, and they are not fallacies, only vague shorthands. "Generics are statements such as “tigers are striped”, “a duck lays eggs”, “the dodo is extinct”, and “ticks carry Lyme disease”. Generics express generalizations, but unlike quantified statements, generics do not carry information about how many members of the kind or category have the property... We accept “ticks carry Lyme disease”, even though very few ticks (approximately one percent) actually have the property."

As others have pointed out, it is true given some men do that. Since the plural is chosen, one could argue that some cannot legitimately be translated in the usual way into logic (i.e. there exists [at least] one) since there need to be at least two men. This still leaves more than enough space for me as part of the group not sexually harassing or assaulting women.
Things would be quite different if the quantifier "all" would be used.

You ask about this proposition:

Men sexyally harass and assault women, but if you're a man that doesn't do this then this statement does not apply to you

There is no fallacy here. It is not stated in precise logical rigour, but it can be interpreted as simply saying there exist men who sexually harass and assault women. Clearly this statement only applies to men who actually do those things. The second part goes without saying, but that doesn't make it a fallacy.
Said another way:

there exist some X that are Y
if there exist some X that are not Y, then they are not Y

No fallacy there.

Identifying logical fallacy: "X are Y, but if you are X who doesnt do Y then this statement does not apply to you."
I saw this post in two ways. The first produces a contradiction. If ‘X are Y’ means that ‘All X are Y’, then it is impossible for there to be an X who does not do Y. These two statements are internally contradictory.
The second way is a straightforward example of definition. Together the two statements say that something applies to you unless it does not. I realize that solution is trivial, but that is what it says.

I'm going to simply combine parts of different answers here I think are relevant since a lot of the answers only seem to have parts.
You ask:

Men sexually harass and assault women, but if you're a man that doesn't do this then this statement does not apply to you.'

First, Conifold's comment "These are called generic generalizations, and they are not fallacies, only vague short-hands." points in the direction of Quantifiers and Quantification (SEP). That there is a name for the first complete thought, the generic generalization (SEP), allows us to emphasize that the first clause in this compound sentence has ambiguity (SEP). One can infer that the subject of the sentence refers either to all or some.
If the first clause is taken to mean all men, then clearly, the claim would be false and likely the product of a hasty generalization. (Remember, a fallacy characterizes an inference, not a proposition.) There are strong political currents right now in the US, that might produce claims that men are inherently rapists, as absurd as most people would consider such a claim. Given presumably that the incidence of rape is below 5% in the general population (and I imagine figures vary widely by researchers), one would have a hard time arguing all or even most men are rapists.
I believe on reading that the most common inference likely to be drawn from the first clause your language asserts is 'Generally men are rapists'. This means even a literal claim of 'Some men are rapists' has the potential to be abused, because 'some' itself is ambiguous. Some might be 1 or might be the majority or even almost all. The reason I read into this is because of the second clause which seems to act as an exclusionary locution. It is as if one is saying:

Generally men are rapists, but if you claim you are not, then present company excepted.

It resembles a No True Scotsman in that it deals with exceptions with categories, but NTS is an attempt to save a category by excluding members based on capricious and ad hoc grounds. In the text you present, it seems more like a claim is made about the general nature of men as perpetrators, and then the dispensation is granted to the hearer. In other words, it seems like the assertoric force also carries over to another transformation:

You may not be a rapist, but men sexually harass and assault women.

And such a claim is very strong if worded such a way even without the explicit use of a quantifier in the second clause. So, I'd double-down on hasty generalization on the condition that the assertion is part of an argument. Generally an argument has at least one explicit premise and a conclusion, and I don't see that at all here. And of course, the final caveat is that context ultimately helps determine meaning, so without more of the passage or conversation, it's hard to be definitive.

It's the fundamental attribution fallacy; the speaker incorrectly attributes property Y to all members of X, then partially recognizes the error in their reasoning and attempts to backtrack without walking back the original rhetorical claim. The remedy is to pin the speaker to the point and force them to explicitly acknowledge that Y is not a property of members of X.

No downvote, but the fundamental attribution error is when we are biased between occurrence and disposition whether we are talking about ourselves or strangers. That is, we assign negative experiences to personality of others, but our own negative performance is assigned to situational factors. Thus we put a positive spin on our own failings as occurrences, but put a negative spin on attributions of others as dispositions.  I don't believe the attribution has anything to do with rhetoric at all, but is a systematic error in theory of mind.
